# Tab problems in Android/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, tabs

I am new to android development/eclipse and have run into a problem.  I have 3 working apps that I programmed that work by themselves.  One of these is a app that simply displays 2 tabs that when clicked don't really do anything.  What I need to do is integrate my three programs together so that when you click on the tabs they start the other 2 apps.  My biggest problem right now is the layout.  I have them all together and compiled with no errors, but when I run it everything is displayed with the tabs and its a mess.  My question is, how can I make it so that only the right stuff displays only when a tab is clicked.  My xml file is a jumbled mess with like three different LinearLayouts.  I am so new I don't know where to start.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Brian

Comment: - Create an MainActivity that has Two tabs (looks like you already have that)
- Create Two separate fragments with the content of each tab. 
- Add an OnTabChangedListener to the Activity and show/hide the fragments based on the tab selected.

Answer (score 0):

What is displayed on the screen at one time is called an Activity. Looks like you want 3 activities, but what you have is only one Main Activity. You should display the 2 tabs on the Main Activity and then use an Intent to change between activities, when you press on the tabs.
For a reference, you can refer to the android developer site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
I hope this helps!